# jqgrid check before clicking add button

Tags: jqgrid, treegrid

for a treegrid i want to enable the add button only if a record is selected. if that is not possible on clicking the add button i would like to see if the rowid selected is not null.

Any ideas i tried the beforeshowform i could not figure out how to skip adding the form.

```
beforeShowForm: function(formid) {
  var rowid = jQuery("#treegrid").getGridParam('selrow');
    if(rowid == null ) {
         return[false,"Please select a row."]; 
    } else {
         return[true,""];
    }
}
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373693/jqgrid-how-to-set-toolbar-options-based-on-column-value-in-row-selected/5376355#5376355) I created [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/EdableDisableEditDelNavigatorButtons.htm). In the demo I made the first row 'not-editable-row' so the "Add" and "Edit" buttons from the navigation bar will be disabled on the row selection. If one selects the second row the "Add" and "Edit" buttons will be enabled. If one unselect the row, so no rows are selected the "Add" and "Edit" buttons will be disabled one more time.

You can use the same idea in case of the treegrid.