# Only allow delete on some row in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a problem with `jqGrid`. Suppose I have define a grid like that:

```
 $(function(){      
    $("#crud").jqGrid({
    url: '<c:url value="/log4jConf.html?method=getJSONProperties"/>',
    editurl: '<c:url value="/log4jConf.html?method=updateProperties"/>',
    datatype: 'json',
    colNames:['Key','Value'],
    loadonce: true,
    colModel:[
        {name:'key',index:'key',width:453,editable:true},
        {name:'value',index:'value',width:741, editable:true},
    ],
    pager: '#pcrud',
    rowNum:30,
    rowList:[30,40,50],
    viewrecords: true,
    caption:'Log4j Properties',
    height: 'auto',
    });
    jQuery("#crud").jqGrid('navGrid',"#pcrud",{edit:false,add:false,del:true});
    jQuery("#crud").jqGrid('inlineNav',"#pcrud");
});
```

And I only want to allow delete action on the row has `key = "aaaa"`. How should I do?

Comment: please see the thread...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735560/show-hide-jqgrid-delete-button

Comment: this demo matches your reqirement i guess..
http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/EdableDisableEditDelNavigatorButtons.htm