# How do you dynamically change the navGrid toolbar icons in jqgrid?

Tags: dynamic, jqgrid

I currently have a a pretty standard jqgrid that I would like to change the navGrid icons dynamically. The grid shows some standard data with limited navGrid icons (like search) but if you log in to the site it will allow you do add, edit, etc. So I would like to turn on/off certain icons under certain situations. I have not been able to find any way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/HideShowNavGridButtonsDynamically.htm) which I made for [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056859/jqgrid-resolve-the-grid-pager-id-dynamically/7057838#7057838). [Another demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/EdableDisableEditDelNavigatorButtons.htm) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373693/jqgrid-how-to-set-toolbar-options-based-on-column-value-in-row-selected/5376355#5376355) shows one how to disable/enable buttons from the navigator bar instead of show/hide there. I think it's what you can do.