# Need to disable the button present in the bottom of jqGrid dynamically

Tags: jqgrid

Currently, I am working on asp.net mvc2 project which has a view containing three dropdown controls. I am also using jqGrid for displaying the data in the application. The jQGrid is displayed with buttons called Add,Edit,Search in the footer section. I need to disable and enable the Search button dynamically. If the user selects any item from dropdown1 and dropdown2 then I need to disable the Search button and in case the user selects any item from dropdown3 then I need to enable the Search button.

I am new to jQGrid implementation. Can anyone help me with some sample code to handle the above functionality.

Thanks & Regards,
Santosh Kumar Patro

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to read [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7057838/315935) and [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5376355/315935). The answers shows how one can hide/show or enable/disable buttons from the navigator bar. You can use `onSelectRow` or `beforeSelectRow` callback to disable/enable/hide/show the navigator buttons dynamically.

Comment: He wants to disable the search button as per the selection of drop down controls, So I think instead of onSelectRow he needs to use dataEvent to disable /enable the search buttons

Comment: @Kris: I was not sure *when* you what to enable/disable the button. In any way you can follow the referenced answers to access the Search button. It has the id which will be constructed from 'search_' prexix and the gridId.