# Enable/Disable a custom button in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am creating a custom button by using "navButtonAdd". I want to enable/disable this button.
How do I do this?

```
grid.navButtonAdd("#pg_List1_toppager", { caption: "", buttonicon: "icon-archive", onClickButton: customSearch, position: "first", title: "Archive", cursor: "pointer", disabled: "disabled" });
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all I would recommend you to use `id` option of [navButtonAdd](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_buttons) which allows assign `id` attribute to the button. It makes easier to address the button later. To disable the button you can add class `"ui-state-disabled"` to it. To enable the button you can remove buttons.

I would recommend you to examine [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/EdableDisableEditDelNavigatorButtons.htm) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5376355/315935) and [another demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/HideShowNavGridButtonsDynamically.htm) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7057838/315935) which hide/show non-active buttons of navigator bar.

Comment: WOOOW you're like a Superman :D.I change grid.navButtonAdd("#pg_List1_toppager", { id:"btn" }) and when i use $('#btn' + gid).addClass('ui-state-disabled') not work

Comment: @ZSH: Why you use `+ gid` after `'#btn'` in the selector? You have to use `$('#btn' + gid).addClass('ui-state-disabled')` only if you use `grid.navButtonAdd("#pg_List1_toppager", { id:"btn" + gid, ...})`. If you use just `id:"btn"` then your code should be `$('#btn').addClass('ui-state-disabled');`