# Disable a row in jQGrid

Tags: jqgrid, disabled-control, javascript

I want to disable 1 row on my grid depending on the value of a global javascript variable. For example, lets say the value of this variable is 123. Then any row which has 123 in a column called "XYZ" should be disabled.

where would be the best way to implement such a functionality ? inside loadcomplete or beforeselectrow ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way for inline editing mode is adding `not-editable-row` class to the row. You can use `rowattr` to add the class based on the content of some column. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10531680/315935) for details.

If you use form editing you have to choose another way. It you use `navGrid` then you can disable some editing or hide buttons based on the value in the column of selected row. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5376355/315935) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7057838/315935) for more details. `beforeSelectRow` is good place for such changes.

Comment: @user2334092: You are welcome! The usage of `rowattr` is really the best way from performance point of view because if you use `gridview: true` (you should use it always) the full grid body will be placed on the page as *one operation*. If you change the grid body inside of `loadComplete` it will work always slowly because the changes of one element on the page follow to [reflow](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/reflow) of *all existing elements on the page*. See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12519858/315935) for more details.