# How to disable jqgrid row cell?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I want to disable row cell in Jqgrid in loadcomplete . I am using this code:

```
loadComplete: function () {

                var ids = $grid.jqGrid('getDataIDs');
                for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {

                    var rowId = ids[i];
                    var rowData = $grid.jqGrid('getRowData', rowId);
                    if (rowData.IsActive) {
                        rowData.Save.attr("disabled", true); //Error comes here

                    }

                }
            }
```

if is active cell is true i want to disable col cell save disabled. If condition running fine but in " rowData.Save.attr("disabled", true);" (Save is the column name) it does not work. It show error it is not a function. How can i do ths?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable a row in jQGrid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17818891/disable-a-row-in-jqgrid)

Comment: I suppose that you use wrong terminology. One can **disable** only elements on HTML page which have user interaction. For example you can disable `<input>` or `<select>` element, but you can't disable the cell of the grid which is `<td>` element. If you want to change **the color** of the cell you can assign `ui-state-disabled` class to the cell. Probably you want to deny *editing* of the cell? In any way you should clear describe your goals and what you mean under disabaling the cell.

Comment: The current code use `getRowData` to get **the data** (**the text**) from the row. `rowData.Save` is string which one get from the column `"Save"` (if you have the column. you should post `colModel` in the case too). It's **not** the DOM element which attributes you can change.

Comment: OLEG how can i disable row?  Is there any other way

Comment: I want to disable Save col if isactive is true.

Comment: Please use "@Oleg" in comments if more as one person wrote comments before. I can repeat that disabling of the row, which contains only the text, or disabling the text in "Save" column have no sense. You can't disable something, which is not enabled. The simple text is not enabled and so it can't be disabled. You don't posted **how the grid looks like** and **what you have in the column "Save"**. You can include pictures, `colModel` and to describe **which changing of the behavior of the row/cell you expect from "disabling"**.

Answer (score 0):

How about this
rowData.jqGrid('setColProp', 'YouColumnName', {editable:false});