# How to conditionally hide/show the Add/Edit form of the jqgrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

How to conditionally hide/show the Add/Edit form of the jqgrid? I have tried the following:

```
afterShowForm:function(formid) {                            
    jQuery('form#'+formid).hide();           
    jQuery('.jqmOverlay').hide();   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would don't recommend you to hide the form under some condition. The user will click on the Add or Edit button and it would just nothing happens? I think it could be misunderstood the user.

Instead of that you can disable/enable or hide/show some from editing buttons of `navGrid`. [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5376355/315935) demonstrate (see [the old demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/EdableDisableEditDelNavigatorButtons.htm)) how to make enable/disable buttons conditionally. [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7057838/315935) (see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/HideShowNavGridButtonsDynamically.htm)) shows how to show/hide buttons of `navGrid`.