# Jqgrid- Enable add row just if there is a selected row

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I tried to change the text of the dialog,
but when I need again the original dialog, it already not good any more

if you have better idea to force the user to select row when he add a new row 
I will be vary happy.
      //ADD

```
    url: 'Handler.ashx',
    closeOnEscape: true,
    closeAfterAdd: true,
    reloadAfterSubmit: true,      
    drag: true,
    beforeShowForm: function (frm) {
        if ($("#Grid1")[0].p.selrow == null) {                       
            $("#TblGrid_Grid1").text("Please, select row");
            $("#edithdGrid1").text("Warning!");
            $("#cData").text("OK");
            $("#sData").hide();
        }

        }



    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable Add button if no row is selected. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5376355/315935) for more details. To disable the button you need just add `ui-state-disabled` class to the "Add" button. The id of Add button is "add_Grid1" if the id of the table is `Grid1`. Inside of `beforeSelectRow` you can remove `ui-state-disabled` class to enable the button. If the grid reloaded (inside of `loadComplete`) and no rows selected you can disable the Add button too.

One more option will be to hide the button instead of making it disabled. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7057838/315935) for more details.