# Disable 'Warning Dialog' in jqgrid Edit/Delete

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using `jqgrid` inline edit in my application which is also accessed in mobile. Since the user access space in the mobile is small i dont want the pop-up's throwing in the middle.

So, basically when the user did not select the row and click the edit/delete button the warning dialog is thrown **"Please, select a row"**. Now i did not want the alert. Just when the user click on the edit/delete button without selecting the row it should stand still. Nothing happens.

Is this possible? How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you another way. One can disable or hide Delete/Edit buttons until a row will be selected. Inside of `loadComplete` one should test whether any row is selected (it could be selected if you use reloadGrid with `{current:true}` option for example). In the case you can disable or hide Delete/Edit buttons once more.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/EdableDisableEditDelNavigatorButtons.htm) created for [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5376355/315935) shows how to disable navigator buttons by adding `ui-state-disabled` class. [Another demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/HideShowNavGridButtonsDynamically.htm) created for [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7057838/315935) demonstrates in interactive form how to show/hide navigator buttons.

Comment: It didn't work when disabling the icons in "loadComplete",   loadComplete: function () {
$("#CommentsData_iledit").addClass('ui-state-disabled');                                   $("#del_CommentsData").addClass('ui-state-disabled');                               }}, any idea?

Comment: @SanthoshKumar: Which *datatype* you use? For example if you use `datatype: "local"` together with `data` parameter then `loadComplete` will be called at the first time *before* `navGrid` and `inlineNav` creates the corresponding buttons. So you have to disable the buttons not only inside of `loadComplete` but after `navGrid` and `inlineNav` too. You should append the text of your question with the current code which not yet work if my last tip will don't help you.

Comment: You are right. Added after the creation of the pager. Can you look into this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27268215/disable-next-last-pager-in-jqgrid