# Disable Next/Last Pager in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using `jqGrid` in which the `Next/Last` pager is enabled even when there is no records in the jqgrid during a filter condition is applied.

I have a demo of `@Oleg`, in which first select "5" in the number of rows displayed in the pager. Then filter the grid in which it shows no records. Now you can see the `Next/Last` pager button still enabled while the `Previous/first` is disabled.

I need to disable the `First/Previous`, `Next/Last` and the `rowList`(5,10,20,50).

I'm using the `datatype:local` but i dont use `loadonce:true`.

Here is the [Demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/MultisearchFilterLocalAtStart2.htm)

Comment: You should **always** include `datatype` which you use and whether you use `loadonce: true` (if you use `datatype: "json"` or `datatype: "xml"`). The requirements about `rowList` isn't clear for me. First of all the value is array and can't be string like "5". It required you can disable it too inside of `loadComplete` base of your criteria (which are currently not clear for me).

Comment: `dataType:local` is wrong You mean sure `datatype: "local"`.

Comment: its datatype: 'local', sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you use `datatype: "local"` or `datatype: "json"` or `datatype: "xml"` together with `loadonce: true`. In the case I would recommend you to add the following `localReader`:

```js
localReader: {
    page: function (obj) {
        if (obj.rows == null || obj.rows.length === 0) {
            return "0";
        }
    }
}
```

It should fix the problem with enabled Next and Last buttons in the pager.

Comment: The pager is showing "10" as default and when clicking then next it shows nothing. Why? There are 7 pages and only 61 records. Its showing me the row numbers from 91-100. Not sure.

Comment: I need the pager buttons to be disabled.

Comment: @SanthoshKumar: Sorry, the code of `page` function should be more simple. I fixed it in my answer.

Comment: Can you look into this please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27287447/cancel-edit-event-in-jqgrid-inline-edit

Answer (score -1):

Debugging the code i found this, Modifying the code of @Oleg.

This works fine for me:

```
localReader: {
    page: function (obj) {
        if (obj.rows == null || obj.rows.length === 0) {
            return "0";
        } 
    }
}
```

The `else` part gets the row count of the page and bind it to the `pager`. So the grid gets collapsed.

Thanks @Oleg for your answer.