# Cancel edit event in jqGrid inline edit

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using `jqgrid inline edit` in which i have a scenario to invoke the `"cancel edit"` button event and throw a message **"Are you sure to cancel?"**.

//Code:

//Unload the grid.

```
$('#CommentsData').jqGrid('GridUnload');

               //Comments grid start.
               $("#CommentsData").jqGrid({

                   datastr: tableSrc,
                   hoverrows: false,
                   datatype: "jsonstring",
                   jsonReader: {
                       id: 'CommentId',
                       repeatitems: false
                   },
                   height: 'auto',
                   width: 'auto',
                   hidegrid: false,
                   gridview: true,
                   sortorder: 'desc',
                   sortname: 'DateTime',
                   pager: '#CommentsPager',
                   rowList: [],             // disable page size dropdown
                   pgbuttons: false,        // disable page control like next, back button
                   pgtext: null,            // disable pager text like 'Page 0 of 10'
                   viewrecords: false,      // disable current view record text like 'View 1-10 of 100' 
                   caption: "Comments",
                   colNames: ['DateTime', 'UserName', 'Comments'],
                   colModel: [

                       {
                           name: 'DateTime', index: 'DateTime', width: 120, formatter: "date", sorttype: "date",
                           formatoptions: { srcformat: "ISO8601Long", newformat: "m/d/Y h:i A" }
                       },
                       { name: 'UserName', index: 'UserName' },
                       { name: 'CommentText', index: 'CommentText', editable: true }],

                   //Events to add and edit comments.
                   serializeRowData: function (postdata) {

                       var filterResult;
                       var jsonResult;

                       if (tableSrc == "")
                           jsonResult = $.parseJSON(commentDetails);
                       else
                           //Parse values bind to the comments.
                           jsonResult = $.parseJSON(tableSrc);

                       var newResult = new Object();

                       //Check if operation is edit.
                       if (postdata.oper == "edit") {

                           //Filter the edited comments from main source.
                           newResult = Enumerable.From(jsonResult).Where(function (s) { return s.CommentId = postdata.id }).First();
                           newResult.CommentText = postdata.CommentText;
                       }
                       else {
                           filterResult = Enumerable.From(jsonResult).First();

                           newResult.CommentText = postdata.CommentText;
                           newResult.TransactionId = filterResult.TransactionId;
                           newResult.TaskId = filterResult.TaskId;
                       }

                       filterResult = JSON.stringify(newResult);

                       $.ajax({
                           url: '@Url.Action("UpdateComments", "Home")',
                           datatype: 'json',
                           data: { 'resultData': filterResult, 'action': postdata.oper },
                           type: 'POST',
                           success: OnCompleteComments,
                           error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                               if (xhr.statusText == "Session TimeOut/UnAuthorized") {
                                   alert(xhr.statusText);
                                   window.location.href = '@Url.Action("LogOut", "Account")';
                               }
                               else
                                   alert(xhr.responseText);
                           }
                       });
                       //After update Load the grid.
                       function OnCompleteComments(result) {
                           selectTaskComment = false;
                           $('#dialog').dialog("close");
                           myfilter = $("#TransactionsGrid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "postData").filters;
                           rowList = $('.ui-pg-selbox').val();

                           Loadgrid($("#TransactionsGrid").getGridParam('page'));

                       }

                   },

                   onSelectRow: function (id) {
                       selectTaskComment = true;
                       var thisId = $.jgrid.jqID(this.id);

                       $("#" + thisId + "_iledit").removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                       $("#del_" + thisId).removeClass('ui-state-disabled');

                       var selectValues = jQuery('#CommentsData').jqGrid('getRowData', id);
                       thisId = $.jgrid.jqID(this.id);

                       if (selectValues.UserName == '@ViewBag.UserName' || '@ViewBag.IsAdmin' == 'True') {
                           $("#" + thisId + "_iledit").removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                           $("#del_" + thisId).removeClass('ui-state-disabled');

                       }
                       else {

                           $("#" + thisId + "_iledit").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
                           $("#del_" + thisId).addClass('ui-state-disabled');

                       }

                   }

               });

               jQuery("#CommentsData").jqGrid('navGrid', '#CommentsPager', { edit: false, add: false, del: true, search: false, refresh: false }, {}, {},

                   {
                       //Delete event for comments
                       url: '@Url.Action("UpdateComments", "Home")',
                       serializeDelData: function (postData) {
                           return {
                               resultData: JSON.stringify(postData.id),
                               action: JSON.stringify(postData.oper),
                           }
                       },
                       errorTextFormat: function (xhr) {
                           if (xhr.statusText == "Session TimeOut/UnAuthorized") {
                               window.location.href = '@Url.Action("LogOut", "Account")';
                           } else {
                               return xhr.responseText;
                           }
                       },
                       beforeSubmit: function () {

                           myfilter = $("#TransactionsGrid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "postData").filters;
                           return [true, '', ''];
                       },
                       afterSubmit: function (response, postdata) {
                           selectTaskComment = false;
                           Loadgrid($("#TransactionsGrid").getGridParam('page'));

                           return [true, '', ''];
                       }

                   });

                   $('#CommentsData').jqGrid('inlineNav', '#CommentsPager', { edit: true, add: true, save: true, del: false, cancel: true });

                   $("#CommentsData_iledit").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
                   $("#del_CommentsData").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
```

In which event i have to write the code and throw the alert message?

Also if possible, need to know if the above code could be optimized. Because the delete event is written in a separate place comparing edit and add. I'm bit confused if this is right method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to invoke the "cancel edit" button would be executing the code

```js
$("#CommentsData_ilcancel").click(); // trigger click event on Cancel button
```

where `CommentsData` is the id of the grid.

Comment: This works too good. But is there any way like we have for add, edit and delete "onclickSubmit"? something like that?

Comment: @SanthoshKumar: Inline editing have no "onclickSubmit" (only Delete has it), but you can use `beforeSaveRow` callback which have two parameters: `option` and `rowid`. You can return `false` from the callback to spot submitting. Return true or undefined means to allow to save the row.

Comment: My way of inline edit method is the correct way? Right?

Comment: @SanthoshKumar: I'm not sure what you mean. The choice of editing mode (inline editing, form editing or cell editing) depended on the project requirements. Even if you choose inline editing you have choice to start editing directly (call `editRow`) on click on the row, on double-click on the row and so on. You can use `formatter: "actions"` or `inlineNav`.

Comment: @SanthoshKumar: The choice heavy depend on your requirements. For example you use grid with no pager. I hope you set `rowNum` to large enough value to see more as the first 20 rows in the page. In case of large number of rows **the user will have to scroll to the bottom** to be able to start/stop editing. It's clear disadvantage. On can use context menu with the same actions alternatively. Another example: one can save or discard editing rows on click on another row. The choice depend on the project requirements. So one have many alternative and the choice depend on requirements.

Comment: That's right Oleg. But i was asking the code that i mentioned above for inline edit is correct and simple. I thought the coding part was not correct for the method i used. That's why.

Comment: @SanthoshKumar: Many parts of the posted code are unclear for me. You use `Enumerable.From(jsonResult)`. What is that? You call `Loadgrid` function. What it do? Where is the code? You use undeclared `commentDetails` or `tableSrc` inside of `serializeRowData`. All looks very strange. You use `serializeRowData` in definitively wrong way. The callback will be called to serialize `postdata` object before making Ajax call. Instead of that you don't return any data and makes *separate* Ajax request. So many parts looks unclear, strange and suspected for me because I don't understand your goals.

Comment: Thanks for you detailed comment. I'll post it as a new question with a demo. Thanks again.