# jqGrid 'clearToolbar' without grid reload

Tags: jqgrid

I need to clear the `toolbar` without reloading the grid in my `jqgrid`. It should just reset the toolbar to its default values.

I tried using,

```
$("#TransactionsGrid")[0].clearToolbar();
```

My grid `datatype:local` and i don't use `loadonce:true`.

This made the `toolbar` clear and refresh the grid. I dont want that to happen.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the question interesting.

To implement the requirement I suggest to use register `jqGridToolbarBeforeClear` to execute the handler only once. The handler should 1) unregister itself as the event handler and return "stop" to prevent reloading of the grid:

```js
$grid.jqGrid("filterToolbar", { defaultSearch: "cn" });
$("#clearToolbar").button().click(function () {
    var myStopReload = function () {
            $grid.unbind("jqGridToolbarBeforeClear", myStopReload);
            return "stop"; // stop reload
        };
    $grid.bind("jqGridToolbarBeforeClear", myStopReload);
    if ($grid[0].ftoolbar) {
        $grid[0].clearToolbar();
    }
});
```

[The corresponding demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/clearToolbarWithoutReload.htm) shows it live.

Comment: That's perfect as usual. Thanks @Oleg. Can you please look into this also? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27287447/cancel-edit-event-in-jqgrid-inline-edit