# jgGrid and event ResetFilterToolbar

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I use last version free-**jqGrig** by **Oleg**.

I know that in versions, free-**jqGrid**, many other events are added in difference from jqGrid.

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#list_of_events

Has re-read many similar answers, but events don't work for me.

[jqGrid 'clearToolbar' without grid reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27290220/jqgrid-cleartoolbar-without-grid-reload)

Here something similar, but in an example an event when pressing the custom button.
It is necessary for me that when pressing on to **ClearToolbar** to add the custom check on event "**jqGridToolbarBeforeClear**" or "**jqGridToolbarAfterClear**".

Comment: You wrote about "custom button". Could you explain what you exactly do and describe more detailed what you try to implement? Do you added in some way custom button to the **searching filter toolbar** (see `filterToolbar`) or you mean **navigator bar** (see `navGrid`)? It can be that the events jqGridToolbarBeforeClear and jqGridToolbarAfterClear are not the events, which you really need. Which `datatype` you use? In general, it's helpful in the most cases if you post JavaScript code or the demo, which shows what you do.

Comment: You wrote about "the custom check on event jqGridToolbarBeforeClear or jqGridToolbarAfterClear". Do you need to **stop** processing in some cases? It's possible only in `jqGridToolbarBeforeClear` and only. It should return `"stop"` value.

Comment: Thanks Oleg for the answer .Yes I have to stop processing of the filter in certain cases. I use only filterToolbar. datatype: 'json'

Comment: I try:     $("#jqGridP").unbind("jqGridToolbarBeforeClear", function(){
      console.log('11111');
      return "stop";
    });
    $("#jqGridP").bind("jqGridToolbarBeforeClear", function(){
      console.log('22222');
      return true;
    });

Comment: I'm not sure that you correctly understand **when** `jqGridToolbarBeforeClear` be triggered. I suppose that you just use wrong event. In what situation you want to prevent processing? Could you describe the test case more detailed?

Comment: When one of filters contains "test" value for example, further operation of filters has to be stopped until this value is cleared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason of your problem is the usage of **wrong event**. The event `jqGridToolbarBeforeClear` will be triggered inside of the method `clearToolbar`, but you want to prevent processing of reloading of the grid inside of `triggerToolbar`. Thus you should use `jqGridToolbarBeforeSearch` event instead.

The mostly correct implementation of event handler `jqGridToolbarBeforeSearch` looks like the following:

```
$("#grid").on("jqGridToolbarBeforeSearch", function (e) {
    var filters = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "postData").filters;
    if (typeof filters === "string") {
        filters = $.parseJSON(filters);
    }
    if (filters) {
        /* add here you custom tests */
        return "stop";
    }

    return e.result; // forward the result of the last event handler
});
```

The main advantage of the usage events comparing to callback is the following: one can define multiple event handlers, but only one callback. If one event  returns "stop" to prevent processing then the next event could *overwrite* the value with another value. To allow to stop processing in case of *any* event handler return "stop" one should use [event.result](https://api.jquery.com/event.result/) in *every* event handler.