# Hide navgrid buttons depending on the number of records in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I need to hide the delete button if there are less than 2 records in the grid. This is the js code. For some reason, the flag `showDelCurrencyButton` is not working out here and is always false.

Any other way to do it?

```
showDelCurrencyButton = false;
grid.jqGrid({
            datatype: 'local',
            jsonReader: jqgrid.jsonReader('CurrCd'),
            mtype: 'POST',
            pager: '#currencyPager',
            colNames: ['Abbrev.', 'Name', 'Symbol'],
            colModel: [
                {
                    name: 'CurrCd', index: 'CurrCd', width: 200, sortable: false,
                    editable: true,
                    edittype: 'select', stype: 'select',
                    editrules: { required: true },
                    editoptions: {
                        dataUrl: getServerPath() + 'Ajax/GetCurrencies',
                        buildSelect: function (data) {
                            var currSelector = $("<select id='selCurr' />");
                            $(currSelector).append($("<option/>").val('').text('---Select Currency---'));
                            var currs = JSON.parse(data);
                            $.each(currs, function () {
                                var text = this.CurName;
                                var value = this.CurCode;
                                $(currSelector).append($("<option />").val(value).text(text));
                            });

                            return currSelector;
                        }
                    }
                },

                { name: 'CurrName', index: 'CurrName', width: 200, sortable: false },
                { name: 'CurrSymbol', index: 'CurrSymbol', width: 200, sortable: false },

            ],
            loadtext: 'Loading...',
            caption: "Available Currencies",
            scroll: true,
            hidegrid: false,
            height: 116,
            width: 650,
            rowNum: 1000,
            altRows: true,
            altclass: 'gridAltRowClass',
            onSelectRow: webview.legalentities.billing.onCurrencySelected,
            loadComplete: function (data) {
                if (data.length > 1) {
                   showDelCurrencyButton = true;
                }
                var rowIds = $('#currencyGrid').jqGrid('getDataIDs');
                $("#currencyGrid").jqGrid('setSelection', rowIds[0]);
            },
            rowNum: 1000
        });
        grid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#currencyPager', {           
            edit: false,
            del: (showDelCurrencyButton == true),
            deltitle: 'Delete record',
            search: false,
            refresh: false
        }
       });
```

Comment: I also tried del: grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'records') > 1 and it also does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code uses `datatype: 'local'` without specifying `data` parameter with input data. It seems strange. In any way you can hide the Delete button dynamically identifying it by id. It's `"del_" + grid[0].id` in your case. Thus you can use `$("#del_" + grid[0].id).hide();` to hide it. By the way one can use `this` instead of `grid[0]` inside of `loadComplete`.

I'd recommend you to read [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7057838/315935) for more details and to read [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5376355/315935), which shows how to disable/enable navigator buttons (like Delete button) instead of hiding.

Comment: $("del_" + grid[0].id).hide(); does not seem to find the delete button so it can't hide it.

Comment: @sarsnake: It should be of cause `$("#del_" + grid[0].id).hide();` because `"del_" + grid[0].id` is the id of the button.

Comment: Thanks Oleg! I just went through my code again and was going to mark this as an answer. Clearly, need more coffee.