# How to show JQuery navigation buttons after showing grid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a few grids that using same code to generate the grid and in all of them the refresh button in grid footer is disabled. There is one grid that I need to show refresh button on it. How can I show the refresh button after generating the grid?

Here is the code that generates the grid.

```
$('#Grid1_grid').jqGrid({
  datatype: 'local',
  data: gridData.records,
  colNames: gridData.colNames,
  colModel: gridData.colModel,
  rowNum: 20,
  shrinkToFit: false,
  autowidth: true,
  rowList: [10,20,50],
  caption: 'Promotion List',
  pager: jQuery('#Grid1_pager'),
  sortname: 'id',
  height: '100%',
  viewrecords: true
}).navGrid('#Grid1_pager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false ,search:false, refresh:false});
```

In other words, I want to set `refresh = true` later in code to show the refresh button of the pager.

Answer (score 1):

One can't show the "Refresh" button if the button was not created. So I suggest you to create *always* the button and show/hide it. The details for the implementation you will find [in the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7057838/315935).

I posted some months before [the feature request](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/be-able-to-hideshowdisableenable-buttons-from-the-navirator-bar/#p24285) with suggestion to change a little the main code of jqGrid (the code of `navGrid`) to solve the problem, but the feature request stay unanswered.