# Hide navgrid in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, webforms

How can hide navgrid in  jgqrid?
I want show jqgrid without navgrid.

Comment: Try some coding and ask help if u got problem in that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need create navigator bar to be able to use [navButtonAdd](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_buttons) or [inlineNav](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#inlinenav) you can use [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator) with corresponding [parameters](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator#parameters)

```
$("#grid").jqGrid("navGrid", "#pager",
    {add: false, edit: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: false});
```

As the result the table with navigator bar will be created, but it will be empty:

[image]

Another way is opposite: you can create navigator grid with all buttons, but hide it immediately. Such behavior could be helpful if you need to show/hide navigator button based on context (depend on selected row for example) or based on the permission of the user on the backend. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7057838/315935) for details.

If you need to hide the whole navigator bar you can use code like

```
$("#pager").find("table.navtable").hide();
```