# jqGrid show hide button navGrid inlineNav

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid jqGrid 4.14.2-pre

How to hide or show buttons depending on the condition

Not using css

```
loadComplete:function(data)
{                   
    if(data.records > 100)
    {
        $('#grid').jqGrid('navGrid','#pager');
        // hide $('#grid').jqGrid('inlineNav','#pager'); ?
    }
    else
    {
        $('#grid').jqGrid('inlineNav','#pager');
        // hide $('#grid').jqGrid('navGrid','#pager'); ?
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you to call both `navGrid` and `inlineNav`, but to hide unneeded buttons identifying there by id. You should just know simple rule how the ids will be build. jqGrid uses prefix build on the navigator button (`"add_"`, `"edit_"`, `"refresh_"`, ...) and the grid id (`"grid"` in your case). See [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7057838/315935) for more details. The method `inlineNav` do the same, but the ids of buttons will be build base on another rule: the grid id and the suffix `"_iladd"` (for Add button), `"_iledit"` (for Edit button), `"_ilsave"` (for Save button) and `"_ilcancel"` (for Cancel button).

Let us you have grid with id="grid". To hide Add button added by `navGrid` you can use `$("#add_grid").hide();`. To hide `inlineNav` Add button you can use `$("#grid_iladd").hide();`.